# Anti-CSRF implementation posting an old token

Tags: php, http-post, csrf

I'm having some trouble with implementing CSRF protection on a login form. Here is the general flow of the login:

This is included at the top of the login page:

```
// Create CSRF token
$token = $auth->random(64); // 64 psuedorandom characters from /dev/urandom
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

The login form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And finally, when the form is submitted further down the page:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    // Bind input to variables
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
    $posttoken = isset($_POST['token']) ? $_POST['token'] : '';

    // Attempt to login
    $auth->login($username, $password, $posttoken);

}
```

The problem starts when $auth->login receives the input. The $_SESSION token is equal to the generated token, but the $_POST token is equal to what the $_SESSION token was during the last submit.

Example var_dumps from $auth->login:

First submit var_dump:

```
$_SESSION Array
[token] => 00a28586a1a89b30149ef130ca6f3c01a25435ad1b0ad1a19326205c75b80d79

$_POST Array
[username] => 
[password] => 
[token] => 2200bb8663f19d66639a7f4791ddb53c9d510802d0ed76c42ac8b3f6d9e1589a
[login] => Login
```

Second submit var_dump:

```
$_SESSION Array
[token] => e093e312b379d766d46083d616fa8655f1565dc19ed6b1f73108546cb5f43fce

$_POST Array
[username] => 
[password] => 
[token] => 00a28586a1a89b30149ef130ca6f3c01a25435ad1b0ad1a19326205c75b80d79
[login] => Login
```

Third submit var_dump:

```
$_SESSION Array
[token] => 8be7ecbdae6274d1ba5ce9e8ace0af7c76e3e7d181c507d3da9b8c35652865cc

$_POST Array
[username] => 
[password] => 
[token] => e093e312b379d766d46083d616fa8655f1565dc19ed6b1f73108546cb5f43fce
[login] => Login
```

If you look carefully you can see the $_POST token is simply shifting downwards -- becoming what $_SESSION was during the last submission.

It has me confused because `$token` and `$_SESSION['token']` are only set once at the top of the page -- they shouldn't be different when the user clicks submit.

To summarize, $_SESSION contains the currently generated token, and $_POST contains the previously generated token.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the session token is being changed before the login handling code, you need to move the token generating bit to happen after the login handling code.

Comment: It seems like this is the issue:

`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">`


When the page is submitted, a new token is generated and added to `$_SESSION` while the old token is passed in `$_POST`, causing the match to fail.

I have yet to find a way around it while still using per-request tokens and keeping both the form and the PHP to handle it on the same page.

Comment: I take that back! The solution was to place the login handling code at the top of the page, the token generating code below it, and finally the form at the bottom. Initially your solution didn't work because the handler was still below the form. Accepted!

Comment: Glad it worked out, I struggled to answer the question because I'm on an iPad. Would have given more info otherwise.